# How to add extension attribute Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, extension-attributes

I'm trying to add an extension attribute to `sales_order` (`\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface`), and I have the following `extension_attributes.xml`:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="order_status" type="string">
            <resources>
                <resource  ref="anonymous"/>
            </resources>
            <join reference_table="aytech_order_approval" reference_field="order_id" join_on_field="entity_id">
                <field>order_status</field>
            </join>
        </attribute>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

I have already created the table `aytech_order_approval` with the fields `order_id` and `order_status`, and in my code I am trying to test getting the attribute like this (I have manually inserted a row into the table with `order_id` = 1 and `order_status` = 'approved':

```
$orders = $this->orderRepository->getList(\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create('Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface'))->getItems();

echo $orders[1]->getExtensionAttributes()->getOrderStatus();
```

However, I keep getting null. What am I doing wrong? Also I've made sure to clear the `var/generation`, and the generated class does indeed have the `getOrderStatus` method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Fortunately or not, but ) Join Processor (Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttribute\JoinProcessorInterface) isn't used everywhere and in particular it is not used in Sales module. As result, extension attributes aren't automatically added to "getList" and "get" methods result for Orders, Invoices and other entities of Sales module. You should do that by yourself, with defining plugin to appropriate method ("getList", "get" or maybe better both). In that plugin you can load all additional data and add it to OrderExtension object.

As a reference example see how it works for GiftMessage module. Three steps to get it done:

1. declare extension attribute: `app/code/Magento/GiftMessage/etc/extension_attributes.xml`
2. declare your plugin:
   `app/code/Magento/GiftMessage/etc/di.xml`
3. add data to OrderExtension object(s) from plugin: `\Magento\GiftMessage\Model\Plugin\OrderGet::afterGetList`

P.S. One small suggestion, for the sake of performance, if you need to extend the collection of objects, try to do that in one call to database storage, and do not do that inside of the loop for every order. But most likely you already know that :)

And here is a code example for your plugin:

```
$ids = [];
foreach ($resultOrder->getItems() as $order) {
    $ids[] = $order->getEntityId();
}
$statuses = []; /* should be loaded for collected $ids */
foreach ($resultOrder->getItems() as $order) {
    $orderId = $order->getEntityId();
    if ($statuses[$orderId]) {
        $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes->setOrderStatus($statuses[$orderId]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in response to your last note, I know how to do this with collections (using `addAttributeToSelect`, etc) but how do I do this with repositories when `getList` returns me an array?

Comment: Also, in the plugin, How am I supposed to get the data (i.e. the order_status) from the table in the database?

Comment: getList does return to you not an array, but Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderSearchResultInterface with getItems() method and it does return an array of OrderInterface objects. You can loop through items and collect ids first, then you need to load additional data from your source table(s) and in another loop set extension attribute value with appropriate setter on auto-generated interface

Comment: in plugin normally you may load additional data with collection related to your custom table(entity).

Comment: updated answer with code snippet

Comment: Ah, so I must define an entity (i.e. a model class) for the custom table? :( I thought the point of extension attributes is so that I can attributes to an existing entity without having to define new entity.. Or perhaps this is only the case for entity where Join Processor is used, which is not the case for Order entity?

Comment: can you able to save the value for this extension attribute