# How to get customer increment_id as extension_attribute in REST order search?

Tags: magento2, extension-attributes

I'm trying to get the customer increment_id to be included as customer_increment_id as an extension_attribute in orders when I search orders through rest/V1/ordes?searchCriteria...

I added following to my modules etc/extension_attributes.xml but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
    <attribute code="customer_increment_id" type="string">
        <join reference_table="customer_entity" reference_field="entity_id" join_on_field="customer_id">
            <field>increment_id</field>
        </join>
    </attribute>
</extension_attributes>
```

I have checked my permissions cleared var/generations/* var/cache/* runed magento setup:upgrade in all possible ways!

So what am I missing?

I have this extension in the same file and that one works fine searching customer via rest/V1/customer/search.

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
    <attribute code="increment_id" type="string">
        <join reference_table="customer_entity" reference_field="entity_id" join_on_field="entity_id">
            <field>increment_id</field>
        </join>
    </attribute>
</extension_attributes>
```

/Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the **JoinProcessor** works exactly.

Anyway, following [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/121159/47466) I actually found out that Resource Models belonging to magento-customer inject a dependency on JoinProcessor while those belonging to magento-sales don't. I think this should explain why the attribute is working in the latter case and not in the former: in this case an **explicit data loading** is required (please have a look to Gift Message case). This can be done for example by using Plugins.

Comment: I had all forgotten about this question. I too have come to this conclution. The join processor isn't added to magento sales. To add customer increment_id to the searchresult would require some plugin or extension work.